# Show hidden element when data-attribute of input changes

Tags: jquery

I have a basic form. Each input is given a data-attribute of `data-input` when the form loads. Each input except the `email` field is hidden. When the user fills out their email, and if we have their info is stored, the other inputs will change to `true` and stay hidden. If we don't, the input data-attribute will be `false` and shown. I'm hiding the label through CSS and want to be able to show the hidden label based on the input if `data-input=false`.

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" data-input>
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" data-input>
    </div>

    <div class="form__btn-group">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label:not([for=email]),
input:not([type='email']) {
    display: none;
}

input[data-input='false'] {
    display: block;
}

input[data-input='true'] {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
if($(input).attr('data-input') === 'false') {
    $('label').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: Why not trigger create a function and trigger that after the email validation has finished?

Comment: You will need to reveal them after the email is entered. I am assuming this is in the `change` callback yet I do not see any callbacks in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through all the `input` that has a `data-input` attribute.

Then, you can use `.prev()` to target the `label`.

```
$("input[data-input]").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).data("input")) {
    $(this).prev("label").show()
  }
})
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[data-input]").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).data("input")) {
      $(this).prev("label").show()
    }
  })
})
```

```css
label:not([for=email]),
input:not([type='email']) {
  display: none;
}

input[data-input='false'] {
  display: block;
}

input[data-input='true'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div class="form__group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form__group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" data-input="false">
  </div>

  <div class="form__group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" data-input="true">
  </div>

  <div class="form__btn-group">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. I've tried the code but noticed that the `labels` were showing prior to the `data-input` equaling `true` or `false`. I'm not sure how to edit your code to reflect this. So, if `data-input=false`, the labels would show.

Comment: It is up to you to set the `data-input` value based on *if we have their info* or not. That has to be done on server side.

Comment: Oddly enough, the labels are hidden, but once the `data-input` changes to `false`, it still doesn't show. Strange.

Comment: Running the code back, I saw the empty data-attribute change to false, hidden input showed, but the label remained hidden.

Comment: I added a snippet... I don't get how you can't have the same result. Post more code if needed.

Comment: Last idea... That may be a document ready issue... I edited again.